# Powershell sort-object for data without a header

Tags: powershell, sorting, object

Is there a way in PowerShell to sort data that does not have a header.  I cannot use `| sort-object dateViewed` because my data does not contain a header.  I could use a script to create a new object with a header, but is there a way to sort by the 3rd column?

If I have a cli API `aws get-vols` that returns data like:

```
disk00   123456  20180103

disk00   222222  20180101

disk00   333333  20180102
```

I'm looking for the easy way out.

```
aws get-vols | sort-object (specify something that means column 3)
```

And i would see:

```
disk00   222222  20180101

disk00   333333  20180102

disk00   123456  20180103
```

Comment: what kind of data are you getting from `aws get-vols` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off using the [AWS PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AWSPowerShell/) instead, which probably returns a real object.

But to answer your question, I will assume the return from `aws get-vols` is a bunch of separate lines, which are really just strings, where each "column" is separated by a <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

In that case, treat it like a CSV with a special delimiter:

```
aws get-vols |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Header Disk,Id,DateViewed |
    Sort-Object -Property DateViewed
```

You can use the same approach if the separator is multiple spaces instead of tab, it's just a little more annoying:

```
aws get-vols |
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        # replace all contiguous whitespace with a comma
        # hope you don't have column values with spaces ;)

        $_ -replace '\s+', ','  
    } |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Disk,Id,DateViewed |
    Sort-Object -Property DateViewed
```

Comment: Your answer worked! The data does have tabs, so your first solution worked as I needed.   I am using the AWS powershell module. In my post, I edited out the AWS details to keep the issue related to powershell. I'm actually calling 'aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filters "Name=volume-id, Values=vol-xxxxxxxxxxx". I also tried Bill_Stewart's solution but ran into a problem (if interested, see below).  it is very cool that with the -header, I can set the column names. Thanks again for the quick help.

Comment: @linux_driver Glad to hear it! But that command doesn't look like the PowerShell module. PowerShell uses `Verb-Noun` syntax, and takes its parameters with a single `-` and spaces between parameter name and value (not `=`). Also, they return actual objects not lines of text. You seem to be using the AWS CLI. I highly recommend going to the PowerShell module if you're going to be using PowerShell to deal with the values, your life will be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you have PowerShell 5.0 or newer, you should be able to say something like this with [the `ConvertFrom-String` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string):

```
aws get-vols | ConvertFrom-String | Sort-Object P3
```

But I agree with [briantist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3905079/briantist) that if there are cmdlets you should use those instead of parsing text.

Comment: This is a good suggestion; `ConvertFrom-String` can do some pretty nice things by just throwing text at it. The only thing I'd caution is that [it isn't yet included in PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/726). It's currently slated for 6.1.0 (but 6.0.0 isn't even out yet, so no idea when or if it will be available again in future versions of PowerShell).

Comment: I tried this but PS threw an error (ConvertFrom-String : The term 'ConvertFrom-String' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...).  Running powershell v 4 on Server 2012 R2. it's cool though because solution from briantist worked fine.

Comment: @linux_driver Bill got the version mixed up. It was introduced in PowerShell v5.

Comment: Correct, it was added in version 5. Sorry for the typo.